# Do you need to release NSData?

Tags: iphone, release, nsdata

```
-(void) func1: (NSData*) somedata
{
    //Processing somedata ....

    [somedata release]; //is it necessay? 
}
```

Comment: There is no possible way to know whether a release is necessary in this scenario.

Comment: You need to provide more information. From your code snippet, there’s no way to know how/when/whether ownership of `somedata` takes place. Consider editing your question and posting the code where you obtain an instance of `NSData *` and how do you pass it to `-func1:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt release `somedata` inside your method.

```
NSData *somedata = [[NSData alloc] init];
func1(somedata);
[somedata release];
```

Assumptions:

- func1 runs on same thread

Comment: How does the original owner of Somedata knows when it's not needed. SomeData would pass into another function, or another object.

Comment: What if the someData is from some complicated delegate function and received as from a callback function.  There is No way to put a [somedata release] in those originated delegate fucntions or anticipated.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, no, you should not release your object. You're not the "owner". As a rule of thumb, you need to release an object once you're done with it only if:

- You allocated it via `[MyClass alloc]`, as in `[[MyClass alloc] init]` or `[[MyClass alloc] initWithFoo:foo bar:baz]`.
- You got a copy via `[someObject copy]` or `[someObject mutableCopy]`.
- You have retained it before.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider releasing it If you are retaining it in this case. But I am not sure because your question does not provide any idea whether a release is required or not. But generally you will `release` objects if you take ownership of it.

Comment: I might be agreeing on this, because you get a hold of someData. The original owner doesn't know whether you are done with the someData. Only you know someData is finished and Not Needed.